# How to get the admin login when a magento website is made live?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, 404-page

I have made a e-commerce website in magento and made it live. The website is ok but when i am typing the admin url, it is showing 404 error. Can anyone say how to solve this error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page

Comment: When we are moving the website to live from a demo server, what all changes are to be done in the database to get the website and admin of the website.

Comment: its still showing 404 error page..

Comment: Are you able to access admin through index.php, I mean try to access admin using `http://yourweb.com/index.php/admin/` if its accessible then you need to verify rewrite module of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the SQL query ?

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%custom_path%';
```

Answer (score 0):

At First, Please clear all cache, from /var folder.

Then Please check your configuration file ( app/etc/local.xml) and make sure that you have "admin" as value in frontName node.

```
<adminhtml>
  <args>
    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
  </args>
</adminhtml>
```

Then please go to phpmyadmin go to core_config_data table then search the path for **web/secure/use_in_adminhtml** ( use operator - **'LIKE %...%'**)
after finding this field set the value from 1 to 0

(value form 1 to 0 , actually allow non-secure access to the admin).

Please do this also let me know.